# Batch file that identfies files based on its folder name

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, directory, filenames

I have a large folder with various subfolders each containing multiple jpg/jpeg files. For example,

```
0 e:\..jpg   
1 e:\front.jpg
2 e:\back.jpg
3 e:\10_40\apopfront.jpg
4 e:\Dominatrix\Dominatrix.jpg
5 e:\# Herr Fuchs & Frau Elster\Feel Musik 8.jpg
6 e:\# Herr Fuchs & Frau Elster\Immer für Immer.jpg
7 e:\# Herr Fuchs & Frau Elster\Märchentanz - Liebe und Strand.jpg
8 e:\# Herr Fuchs & Frau Elster\# Herr Fuchs & Frau Elster.jpg
```

I am looking for a windows batch script to identify those jpg files that either

- include the string "front" (Files 1,3), or
- are exactly named as ".".jpg (File 0), or
- whose names (without extension) exactly match the name of the directory which they are stored in (Files 4,8)

I think a found a proper solution for the first two conditions (drawing the directory onto the batch script):

> ```
> set Exts="*front*.jpg","*front*.jpeg","*..jpg","*..jpeg"
> for /r . %%g in (%Exts%) do  ...
> ```

But I have no solution to also implement the third condition into that loop. Is there an easy way to go? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The patterns `*..jpg` and `*..jpeg` match files whose names could contain something before `..`, which is not what you want, as far as I understand; I would use `..jp??` instead (analogously, I'd also use `*front*.jp??`); so: `for /R "E:\" %%G in ("*front*.jp??","..jp??") do echo %%~G`. For the third item: `for /R "E:\" %%G in ("*.jp??") do for %%H in ("%%~dpG.") do if "%%~nxH"=="%%~nG" echo %%~G`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patterns `*..jpg` and `*..jpeg` of item **1** match files whose names could contain something before `..`, which is not what you want, as far as I understand. I would use a single pattern `..jp??` instead.

Analogously, I would also use one pattern `*front*.jp??` to cover item **2**.

So to cover item **1** and **2**, I would use:

```cmd
for /R "E:\" %%G in ("*front*.jp??","..jp??") do echo %%~G
```

For item **3**, you could use the following:

```cmd
for /R "E:\" %%G in ("*.jp??") do (
    for %%H in ("%%~dpG.") do (
        if "%%~nxH"=="%%~nG" echo %%~G
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "ndir=%CD%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
set "filename=%%~nxF"
echo !filename!|findstr /c:"front" >nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" echo found file: !!a
echo !filename!|findstr /c:"..jpg" >nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" echo found file: !!a
set "filename:-4"
cd ..\
cd %CD%\!filename!
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" echo found file: !!a
cd !ndir!
set "filename:-1"
cd ..\
cd %CD%!filename!
if %%errorlevek%" == "0" echo found file: !!a
pause >nul
```

do not know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%%a\%%~nxa.jpg" ECHO found "%%a\%%~nxa.jpg"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This worked for me on the two files indicated. As expected, it detected but mangled non-ANSI filenames.

Comment: This also works fine ... great to see that many roads lead to Rome^^